# Will I get higher pressure in the shower if I move the water boiler to the attic?

Tags: water-pressure

My current water boiler is in the basement and I would be happy with just a slight increase of pressure in the shower on the 2nd floor. If I move the water boiler to the attic (3rd floor), will the pressure in the shower increase?

By pressure I mean the amount of water :)

EDIT:

Everyone understands that there are other factors involved but to clarify, the pipe set already runs from top to bottom, so nothing will be changed there. Please keep this thread and comments to the original question, possibility of water damage, how much it cost to move it etc is not of interest.

The water comes from the municipality through the ground.

Comment: Depends. You haven't told us where your water pressure _comes from_. Are you on a well? Municipality? Please revise to add detail. Chances are the location of a boiler is irrelevant.

Comment: Most likely issue is that you have a low flow shower head, or debris is in the screen, or the flow reducer.  ( others have removed those to get better flow.)

Comment: Moving a boiler from the basment to the attic would be a huge project and expose the whole house to water damage risk. And for what--higher volume flow from the shower!?

Comment: It might also require a significant restructuring of the attic floor to support the weight of the full boiler.

Comment: @Jim Stewart Have you seen my house? If I can have someone help me carry it up it would take me 30 minutes and $30 in material, then probably an hour to remove all the air. All plumbing is available already.

Comment: I have read and heard tales of the damage from water heaters in attics. If they never fail catastrophically, then the attic instalation is great.

Comment: "Please keep this thread and comments to the original question" but often, the question asked is asked on an invalid understanding of the one who asks the question.  Asking _WHY_ is strongly encouraged here, as is offering alternative solutions. So far, the answer to your question is "No", it won't make any significant change to your pressure and it will likely involve great expense and engender great risk. The simple answer to your question is "Yes", but it might not be worth it. We're pointing out that "worth" point. Up to you to decide if you're going to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, *relocating* the boiler won't make a difference to your water pressure. The pressure at the shower is the sum of the pressure available at the point where water service enters your house, minus the pressure losses due to pipe friction (related to pipe diameter and length), loss in the boiler, and loss due to the rise in elevation (0.4 PSI per foot, or 9.8 kPa per meter). The sequence of the components and their relative placement in the house don't matter.

*Re-plumbing* may make a difference if the pipe path is very long or under-sized, but for a hot water use frequently we prefer smaller-diameter pipe so that less time and water are wasted waiting for the hot water to arrive at the fixture.

You may also have flow restrictions. It's possible the boiler could limit flow to assure that its discharge is at the required temperature. It's also possible that your shower valve or shower head have intentional restrictions to reduce water consumption, or simply debris. Comparing the flow at another shower, bathtub filler, or sink may help you identify what's going on. You can literally compare the flows by measuring and comparing the time required to fill a bowl or bucket at each of the fixtures. You also can compare the flow of hot and cold at a fixture to identify whether the boiler is creating a restriction to flow.

Comment: If I have a loss due to elevation, why would I not get an increase when there is a drop?

Comment: "You also can compare the flow of hot and cold at a fixture to identify whether the boiler is creating a restriction to flow." +100! That should be the _first_ thing done. Odds are good that there's simply a flow restricter in the shower head and that both hot & cold are "slow".

Comment: because, @MLEN, that loss is minimal in comparison to the other losses. Also, as noted in comments on your question, there's likely _SIGNIFICANT_ cost (and long-term risk of water damage) in doing the relocation to buy you back that minimal loss.

Comment: @MLEN Yes, you will get an increase when there is a drop. But the water had to get up high _before_ it could drop, and you'll incur extra pressure loss getting it there. Because the pipe is a closed system that loss and gain balance each other out and the net is zero.